# how to select specific date from Oracle linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql

I have oracle linked sever from my sql server and i am trying to pull specific data using specific dates but i am getting this error when i trying to run the query:  literal does not match format string".  Here is my query that i am using:

```
select * from openquery (myLinkedServer, 'SELECT NAME, LOCATION, DATE_HIRED FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE  DATE_HIRED between to_date(''2012-01-01'',''DD/MM/YYYY'') and to_date( ''2012-01-31 23:59:59'',''DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'') ')
```

Please help.  thanks

Comment: Your date value `2012-01-01` does not correspond to your format string `DD/MM/YYYY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Egor Skriptunoff was too shy to make it an answer, I´ll try to steal his well deserved rep:

```
select * from openquery (myLinkedServer, 'SELECT NAME, LOCATION, DATE_HIRED FROM MYTABLE
   WHERE  DATE_HIRED between to_date(''2012-01-01'',''YYYY-MM-DD'')
                         and to_date( ''2012-01-31 23:59:59'',''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'') ')
```

should do the trick.